# Data Science logo improvement

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Data Science is just an absolutely rad field.
Why can't this site get a proper, fancy logo just like Stack Overflow, Ask Different, CrossValidated and so on...!?

Maybe is it just because it's still in beta?

Comment: I highly suggest a Terminator type theme. ;p

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our other CMs from last week: [Custom Data Science design and logo - Information gathering](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/123591) :)

Comment: competed, see https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631/55122

Answer (score 5):

> Maybe is it just because it's still in beta?

Yes, beta sites have generic logos with the initials of the site in most cases.

The logo and the overall site design would be discussed and decided upon after the site gets selected for graduation.

Example: [[Design discussion of the WorldBuilding site]](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2916/13807).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how sites get special logos, but I'm sure we could ask. If you have a proposal, feel free to post it.

Answer (score -2):

I know this can seem overhyped, but many news feeds talking about data science use illustrations based on terminal-like screens full of symbols, typically raining numbers, or just 0s and 1s. Why not a crop similar to the famous Matrix-style image?

[image: Matrix-style logo for data science]

Comment: The problem there is that once its dimensions are rescaled to be just a few pixels across the raining numbers aren't visible anymore - it looks instead like green 'snow' (noise) like on an analogue TV screen.

Comment: @lithic True for a small logo. However, if you look at the recent design for Se.Dsp http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ you can use a wider logo, and the number pattern for the background image

Comment: I personally find the matrix visualization of "data" and AI to be very misrepresentative. Just another movie trope.