# Site design and logo — Draft

Tags: discussion, design

I’m Simon, a designer at Stack Overflow and I’ve been tasked with designing a custom theme for this community. I’ve looked at your ideas in [this former post](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/135721), and came up with a design I hope fits you all well. A few key points and major themes I took from your comments and looking at popular posts here:

- You want something clean and simple to convey “clear insights from messy data”.
- You want to be different in colors and imagery from similar SE sites.
- You guys love graphs and data.
- Inspiring keywords: Modern, big data, neural networks, diagrams, histograms, machine learning, insights.

### Primary color scheme

[image: Primary Palette]

I used [picular.co](https://picular.co) to find patterns of color using keywords from data science. Results were mostly hues of blue with a few appearances of purple, orange and green.

### Logo

[image: Data Science Logo]

The logo icon is a flask containing intersecting circles. Concocting data into graphs! Thanks for the idea suggested in the previous post.

The typography is a custom font based on [Gugi](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gugi) which I retraced to more closely look like intersecting lines. I used a different set of colors for the dots to represent the colorful graphs in data visualization, analytics and the likes.

### Icon

[image: Favicon]

### Page Design

[image: Home page]

[image: Question page]

The background contains some mathematical and data analysis references.

### Special illustrations

[image]
*missing 404 page, captcha page, error page*

We hope you enjoy this design, but if something doesn’t feel right, now is your chance to share your feedback. This window for feedback will be open one week. We will then work to incorporate feedback as best as we can, finalize things on our end, and lastly, deliver the design to your site.

Comment: Great! Love the typography.

Comment: As minor as it is, I really love the 404 error: downtrending chart "breaking" and leaking out of the flask, amazing.  Very nice overall!

Comment: How long will it take for the design to go live?

Comment: @oW_ - won't be long now. :). Couple of days at the most, I suspect.

Comment: Awesome work :D

Comment: @Philippe any reason for the delay? can't wait to see the new design :)

Comment: @oW_ Good question. I'm not sure. Let me see what I can find out.

Comment: The final design is now live! See this post for more details: [New design launched](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631/123591)