# New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable design feedback.

I have enjoyed working with you to create this theme. Thank you for being an awesome community, and I hope you enjoy the new design!